# Cylon with MQTT Passing Sensor Data

Tags: mqtt, iot, intel-edison

This is probably easy but I could not locate a solution online. I am working on a weather station project with Cylon and MQTT and attempting to pass a variable into an MQTT push but it is passing the literal text. The publish is successful but it just has "msg" instead of the sensor data. Here is the snippet..

```js
Cylon.robot({
  connections: {
    edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }
  },

  devices: {
    bmp180: { driver: 'bmp180' }
  },

  work: function(my) {
    my.bmp180.getTemperature(function(err, val) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      console.log("\tTemp: " + val.temp + " C");
        
        var msg = { "temperature" : val.temp,
                    "pressure" : val.press,
                    "altitude" : val.alt
                    };
        var msgPressure = { "pressure" : val.press };
        var msgAltitude = { "altitude" : val.alt };
        device
            .on('connect', function() {
                console.log('connect');
                device.subscribe('weather/push');
                device.publish('weather/push', JSON.stringify({ msg: 1}));
                });

        device
            .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
                console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
                });
        
        
    });
}
      
}).start();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify({msg:1})` will generate a string that looks like this: `{'msg': 1}`

You probably want `JSON.stringify(msg)` in your publish line to send the msg object.